# Strategy to properly include Wordpress blog within an AngularJS app

Tags: php, wordpress, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm writing an AngularJS/Express/NodeJS/MongoDB website. Within this website, on the navigation bar, there's a section called "Blog", another section called "Advice articles". I intended to use Wordpress to publish the blog and publishing articles on my site, due to its outstanding ability as a blogging and CMS platform. My question is how to properly integrate Wordpress into AngularJS/Express/MongoDB system? I have come across articles on how to include AngularJS as a Wordpress subpages, but I haven't seen any articles on how to include Wordpress as an AngularJS subpage. Does anyone here know any tips/pointers/articles on such a strategy ?

My current strategy is :

1. Let AngularJS routing service handle the route to "Blog" section.
2. "Blog" section is template, which includes an iframe, that points to the Wordpress site, sth like this :

   `<div>
   <iframe frameborder="0" height="800" width="1200" scrolling="no" ng-src="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=4"></iframe></div>`

I can display the blog by this strategy. But it still a little bit off, I have to do some manual CSS. Is there a better way to do this out there ?

Also since I want to allow the user to comment on page without asking them to log in again. How do I integrate the login done in Express/MongoDB with Wordpress user login, which is a PHP/MySql system. Are there any article out there that shows how to implement this ?

Thanks in advance,

P.S : I do not want to go the route of rewriting my site as a Wordpress plugin, I and my friends want to maintain AngularJS/Express/Node/MongoDb as our primary MVC stack.

Answer (score 0):

My advise is make wordpress API with wordpress plugin, and build  commincation angularJS and wordpress through JSON api , read this [article](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/delivering-wordpress-content-with-web-apps-using-angularjs/)

Comment: yes its also an option, in my posted article author advise to use this one https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/

Comment: yes, I have seen that article, the problem is our site doesn't want to to depend on Wordpress as a platform. Doing your way essentially making Wordpress as our primary platform. We want to use AngularJS/ExpressJS/Node/MongoDB as our primary MVC platform.

Comment: you question "My question is how to properly integrate Wordpress into AngularJS? "

Comment: IMO, the article talks about lots of things that doesn't matter for the purpose of the question. @phamductri, I understand this as simply: 1) Install JSON REST API plugin. 2) Populate your {{blog}} with queries to the API. 3) The end.

Comment: @NarekMamikonyan sorry for the confusion, I want to figure out a way to play Wordpress nice with AngularJS/Express/MongoDB, that's probably more accurate than AngularJS alone. With the criteria of Wordpress being a subpage of angularJS front end. The article basically uses Wordpress as the backend with AngularJS as template engine instead of PHP. No, I don't want that approach.

Comment: than you should create your own wordpress at first , do you need it ?